# Random Effects Tobit Model

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, censoring, nested-data, tobit-regression

I'm studying the effect of various criminal case and court district characteristics on sentence lengths. I was planning on running xttobit in Stata because I have individual defendants/cases within federal court districts and a censored sentence length outcome. I have both an upper and lower limit. A prison sentence of "0" months actually means a non-imprisonment sentence (e.g. probation, fine, etc). In addition, I capped my sentence length measure at "life" (or, 470 months - a common cutoff in this line of research). So now my distribution is bounded at both 0 and 470. Should I run a tobit model [with or without -vce(cluster district)-] before using xttobit to conduct diagnostic and specification tests? Also, I have a binary variable that indicates whether or not someone received imprisonment (0=no prison, 1=prison). Can I run this model with logistic and then run the sentence length model, or should I just use the marginal effects for the sentence length model bc this tells you the odds of imprisonment (given the "0" values)?

Comment: Are all 94 districts in your data?

Comment: I took out DC and the US territories because prior work has shown that these districts differ from those that fall within states. I also had to exclude Hawaii and Alaska because I was missing information for these districts on a subset of variables.